# AggregateException Some services are not able to be constructed

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am getting this error :

> An error occurred while starting the application.
> AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: IPMMS.Business.Managers.Seeding.SeedDataManager Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: IPMMS.Business.Managers.Seeding.SeedDataManager': Unable to resolve service for type 'IPMMS.Database.Context.IPMContext' while attempting to activate 'IPMMS.Business.Managers.Seeding.SeedDataManager'.)

I have il-ilce.json which has all cities and districts belong the cities. Onbuild, when IsSeed is true will insert into database but I got this error.

Code:

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddScoped<CustomerServices, CustomerServices>();
            services.AddScoped<SeedDataManager, SeedDataManager>(); 
        }
```

and also in Startup.cs

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(Configuration.GetSection("IsSeed").Value)) 
{
       var seedManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<SeedDataManager>();
       seedManager.RunSeedData(env.WebRootPath);
}
```

SeedDataManager class is :

```
public class SeedDataManager
    {
        private readonly IPMContext _context;

        public SeedDataManager(IPMContext iPMContext)
        {
            _context = iPMContext;
        }

        public void RunSeedData(string root)
        {
            var data = File.ReadAllText(root + "seedData/il-ilce.json");
            var allData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SeedDataDto>>(data);

            foreach (var city in allData.GroupBy(g => g.City))
            {
                var newCity = new City
                {
                    CityName = city.Key,
                    CountryId = 1,
                    Districts = city.Select(s => new District
                    {
                        DistrictName = s.District
                    }).ToList()
                };
                _context.Cities.Add(newCity);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

appsettings.json  //I add only IsSeed

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "IsSeed": "true"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what the message says. `SeedDataManager` cannot be constructed because the DI framwork doesn't know where to take `IPMContext` which is required by `SeedDataManager` constructor.

```
public SeedDataManager(IPMContext iPMContext)
```

If IPMContext is a DbContext then you could add it in ConfigureServices like so:

```
 services.AddDbContext<IPMContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

Comment: I got this message after your suggestion System.ArgumentException: ''AddDbContext' was called with configuration, but the context type 'IPMContext' only declares a parameterless constructor. This means that the configuration passed to 'AddDbContext' will never be used. If configuration is passed to 'AddDbContext', then 'IPMContext' should declare a constructor that accepts a DbContextOptions<IPMContext> and must pass it to the base constructor for DbContext.'

Comment: I don't know your dbcontext setup. Don't pass the options or create the constructor that takes in the options: `public IPMContext(DbContextOptions<IPMContext> options) : base(options)`